# Stream mysql result Nodejs to AngularJs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

I have a mysql table that contains 45 000 rows.
Im using node-mysql to select all rows : 0.1018 secondes to get results
but when i send response it take 5 secondes to be loaded in angularjs, so If you have an idea to stream result it will help me.
This is my code :
NodeJs Side:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var sqlStudies = "SELECT * from studies order by id desc";

    connection.query(sqlStudies, function(err, studies, fields) {
        // request execution time : 0.1018 secondes
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(studies);

    });

});
```

AngularJs Side: ( getting data to populate table)

```
$http.get('/api/study/').success(function(response) {
    ed.studies = response;

});
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you want to get all 45000 at the same time, not even possible to read 45000 lines at the same time.

Comment: Because im using them to populate table and allow user to filter. it works but it takes 5 seconds to get response from nodejs Server.

Comment: better use pagination, not a good practice to display so many results once.

Comment: even if you stream, DOM will re-render again and again since you will be appending values from stream into scope variable